# Always Center Div with CSS3 Flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="indicator"></div>
<div class="mainPanel">
    <div>Speichern</div>
    <div>Style</div>
    <div>Speichern</div>
</div>
```

The mainPanel contains three elements. The element in the center should always be in the center as shown here:

[image]

When one of the texts is to long it should be capped with ... as shown here:

[image]

Sometime the text on the left or on the right are not of equal size. Even in this case should the text in the center be in the middle.

I created a JSFiddle to show what I did. Here is my CSS code ([Here is the JSFiddle DEMO I created](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/1cfk2x53/).):

```
.indicator {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    z-index: -10;
}
.mainPanel {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.mainPanel > div {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is my problem. When the text on the right or on the left side are not of equals size then the text in the middle is not in the center:

[image]

[Here is the JSFiddle DEMO I created](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/1cfk2x53/).

**How can I get the text in the middle being always in the center and still having the ellipsis property being working?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `flex` property to determine how each `flex` element can expand/contract is going to be your solution here:

## [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cfk2x53/7/)

Here's the important stuff that we're adding:

**CSS**

```
.mainPanel > div {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 1 1 25%; /* <-- Added */
}
.mainPanel > div:nth-child(2) {  /* <-- This whole block added */
    flex: 2 0 auto;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

So here's what that `flex` property is telling you about the layout parameters of your flex box.

**Example:** `flex: 2 0 auto`

- `2` – This is how many "parts" your flex element can grow to.  This can be set individually with `flex-grow`.
- `0` – This is the floor for how many "parts" your flex element can shrink to.  This can be set individually with `flex-shrink`.
- `auto` – This is *essentially* the `min-width` for the element.  It won't be able to shrink beyond that point.  Setting it to `auto` means we size the element to its content.  This can also be set individually with the property `flex-basis`.

Comment: Is there also a way to make the left and the right element at most the size of their content?

Comment: @confile - Start a separate question, maybe?  Not entirely clear what you want from just that.

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557775/how-can-div-elements-take-only-the-space-of-their-inner-content-in-a-css3-flexbo