# How can Div Elements take only the Space of their inner Content in a CSS3 Flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="indicator"></div>
<div class="mainPanel">
    <div>Speichern</div>
    <div>Style</div>
    <div>Speichern</div>
</div>
```

The mainPanel contains three elements. The element in the center should always be in the center as shown here:

[image]

Here is the css code I use

```
.indicator {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    z-index: -10;
}
.mainPanel {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.mainPanel > div {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 1 1 25%;
    border: solid 1px #999;
}
.mainPanel > div:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.mainPanel > div:nth-child(3) {
    background: lime;
}

.mainPanel > div:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 900 0 auto;

    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want that the content in the center cannot grow over the left and right part.

**How can I make it that the left and the right element take as width at most the size of their inner content? How can I achieve that the left and the right element can not be smaller in width than their inner content?**

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible to do in css3 flexbox (yet).  But you could so something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fggxq753/1/

```
z-index: 10;
```

Since you always want the middle text centered regardless of the content of the table, I have removed it from the table and positioned it over the top with a higher z-index.  It works in all browsers apart from safari (due to the lack of flex support).

If you want something working in all browsers, I would just use display: table;

http://jsfiddle.net/fggxq753/2/

The downside to floating the title is that the other cells could overlap it if they are long enough.  To fix this you could use the central cell for the title and auto calculate it's padding using javascript, but then it gets a bit messy.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want that the content in the center cannot grow over the left and right part which happens in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, maybe easier, way to achieve it

```css
.bar {
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;}
  .bar:before, .bar:after {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  .bar:before {
    background-color: red;
    content: attr(data-left);
    left: 0;
  }
  .bar:after {
    background-color: lime;
    content: attr(data-right);
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bar" data-left="L" data-right="Speichern">Style</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle

Comment: This is not what I want. I want that the content in the center cannot grow over the left and right part which happens in your solution.